# Procedure too large; running a sub procedure

Tags: excel, vba

I divided an Excel worksheet into sections, each section being 20 rows (example: Section 1 = rows 132 to 152, Section 2 = rows 153 to 173, etc.).

There are 100 sections. I run a procedure in VBA that, for each section, will hide a certain number of rows based on a desired number of rows for each section. After running the routine on about 23 sections, I get an error

> Procedure too Large

I was told that I should run a sub procedure to solve the problem. I tried `Sub proc1()`.
Here is the first part of the code, followed by the `Sub proc1()`.

I get the following error immediately after the `Sub proc1()` line:

> Ambiguous name detected: Worksheet_Change

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
ActiveSheet.Activate
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("G20"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
Select Case Target.Value
Case Is = "0":  Rows("132:152").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Case Is = "1":  Rows("134:152").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Rows("123:133").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "2":  Rows("135:152").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Rows("123:134").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "3":  Rows("136:152").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Rows("123:135").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "4":  Rows("137:152").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Rows("123:136").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "5":  Rows("138:152").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Rows("123:137").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "6":  Rows("139:152").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Rows("123:138").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "7":  Rows("140:152").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Rows("123:139").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "8":  Rows("141:152").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Rows("123:140").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "9":  Rows("142:152").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Rows("123:141").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "10":  Rows("143:152").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Rows("123:142").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "11":  Rows("144:152").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Rows("123:143").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "12":  Rows("145:152").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Rows("123:144").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "13":  Rows("146:152").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Rows("123:145").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "14":  Rows("147:152").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Rows("123:146").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "15":  Rows("148:152").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Rows("123:147").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "16":  Rows("149:152").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Rows("123:148").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "17":  Rows("150:152").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Rows("123:149").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "18":  Rows("151:152").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Rows("123:150").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "19":  Rows("152:152").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Rows("123:151").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "20":  Rows("123:152").EntireRow.Hidden = False

End Select
End If
```

and so on...then:

```
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("G43"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
Select Case Target.Value
                    
Case Is = "0": Rows("615:635").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Case Is = "1": Rows("617:635").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("615:616").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "2": Rows("618:635").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("615:617").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "3": Rows("619:635").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("615:618").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "4": Rows("620:635").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("615:619").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "5": Rows("621:635").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("615:620").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "6": Rows("622:635").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("615:621").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "7": Rows("623:635").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("615:622").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "8": Rows("624:635").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("615:623").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "9": Rows("625:635").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("615:624").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "10": Rows("626:635").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("615:625").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "11": Rows("627:635").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("615:626").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "12": Rows("628:635").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("615:627").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "13": Rows("629:635").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("615:628").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "14": Rows("630:635").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("615:629").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "15": Rows("631:635").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("615:630").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "16": Rows("632:635").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("615:631").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "17": Rows("633:635").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("615:632").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "18": Rows("634:635").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("615:633").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "19": Rows("635:635").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("615:634").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "20": Rows("615:635").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    
End Select
End If

Call proc1
Call proc2

End Sub

Sub proc1()

If Not Application.Intersect(Range("G44"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
Select Case Target.Value
                    
Case Is = "0": Rows("636:656").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Case Is = "1": Rows("638:656").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("636:637").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "2": Rows("639:656").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("636:638").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "3": Rows("640:656").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("636:639").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "4": Rows("641:656").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("636:640").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "5": Rows("642:656").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("636:641").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "6": Rows("643:656").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("636:642").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "7": Rows("644:656").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("636:643").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "8": Rows("645:656").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("636:644").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "9": Rows("646:656").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("636:645").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "10": Rows("647:656").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("636:646").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "11": Rows("648:656").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("636:647").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Case Is = "12": Rows("649:656").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("636:648").EntireRow.Hidden = False

....and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop and a some math to reduce your code a lot:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const BLOCK_SIZE As Long = 20 '(+1 header)

    Dim n As Long, i As Long, rngCheck As Range, c As Range, rStart As Long

    Me.Unprotect 'use Me to refer to the sheet itself

    Set rngCheck = Me.Range("G20") 'first cell to check
    rStart = 132                   'start row (header) for section 1

    For i = 1 To 100
        
        Set c = Application.Intersect(rngCheck, Target) 'Target intersects with cell being checked?
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            n = c.Value
            If n > BLOCK_SIZE Then n = BLOCK_SIZE                    'limit number of rows to show
            Me.Cells(rStart, 1).Resize(BLOCK_SIZE + 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True       'hide all
            If n > 0 Then Me.Cells(rStart, 1).Resize(n + 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False 'unhide the ones we want
        End If

        Set rngCheck = rngCheck.Offset(1, 0) 'next cell to check
        rStart = rStart + (BLOCK_SIZE + 1)   'next block starting row

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It worked fantastic! I added some code to protect the sheet again after running the routine. You're a life saver....thanks!

Comment: One last question: The code works well...but if I copy a value in cell G20 down to all other cells below (G21 to G119), I get an error: Run-time error '13' Type Mismatch. When I then try to debug, it highlights in yellow the line in the code that reads: n = Target.Value    Is there anyway to allow for copying of figures to more than one cell like this...or is this a limitation I can't avoid?

Comment: Do you need this to respond to multiple cells being updated in one edit?  See edit above.